# How to send a post request to google safebrowsing using the curl in bash?

Tags: bash, curl

I have a very large list of domains that should be checked every day. I need to use a post request. I'm using these instructions https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/lookup_guide#AcceptableUsage. But it does not work, as a result I get an Error 400 (Bad Request).

I am using this code:

```
$ curl -k "https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=api&apikey=hidden&appver=1.0&pver=3.01" -d "NUM=2" -d "URL=test.com ask.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the body you're sending:

```
NUM=1&URL=test.com ask.com
```

This is the body you should be sending

```
2
http://test.com
http://ask.com
```

You could perhaps try

```
curl -k "https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=api&apikey=hidden&appver=1.0&pver=3.01" -d \
'2
http://test.com
http://ask.com'
```